# DIR command don't work with special characters

Tags: batch-file, localization, directory

I have found some files on the server with special characters in the name.
The name is created automatically, so changing them is not an option.

Here an example:

```
H:\>dir /b "LB_20136021 BÁKÁNY*"  //search with wildcard!

LB_20136021 BÁKÁNY MUVEK GÉPIPARI Kft..pdf              //file found!

H:\>dir "LB_20136021 BÁKÁNY MUVEK GÉPIPARI Kft..pdf"    //search with exact name!

 Datenträger in Laufwerk H: ist SATA 1TB

 Verzeichnis von H:\

Datei nicht gefunden                                    //"file not found"?!?!

H:\>
```

There are also other problems with commands in batch files.

Is there a sollution to prevent this, or is this a good example why a batch script should not be used any more? (I still like them, but in advanced scripts there are so many nasty problems...)

Comment: Both __DIR__ command lines work on my computer using OEM 850 code page in console. Which code page is used on your computer for console? Open a command prompt window and run `mode` to see the used code page.

Comment: Maybe you mean the command "chcp"?
"mode" tells me something about the state of my com ports.

Codepage is 850 (dos default)

Comment: wtf, I just created a test file with
`echo asdf > "LB_20131449 BÁKÁNY MUVEK GÉPIPARI Kft..pdf"`
and there is no problem with this file!
There must be something different with the original file!

Comment: copy the code from this site also don't work!
I guess it is now unicode and it looks different in the dos box :(

Comment: `chcp` executed without any parameter as well as `mode` executed without any parameter output both the code page used for console. `mode` additionally outputs for device `CON` also number of lines and columns, key repeat rate and key repeat delay as used for current console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, some hours later I think I have the solution:

The Problem is the U of MUVEK, because it's a hungarian name and it is no U but an Ű

In the dos box it is not visible until you use codepage 852 (suggested for hungary)

so this 
`BÁKÁNY MUVEK GÉPIPARI Kft.`
becomes this:
`BÁKÁNY MŰVEK GÉPIPARI Kft.`

So if you hate someone, use this char...